# What book can I find the Yuan-Ti Pureblood race in?

Tags: dnd-5e, races

What book can I find the Yuan-Ti Pureblood race in?

I know its really simple but I just forgot.

Comment: Are you asking about the PC race? Or the race in general?

Comment: @rubiksmoose I don't know if the OP was asking about PC races or not so it may not be a duplicate. Also, the OP is asking about a specific race and not general books.

Comment: @Eternallord66 Well, if they are actually asking about more than just the PC race, I'll be happy to undo the dupe. As it is, it seems extremely likely that is what they are referring to. Generally when someone is looking for information on a [generic] race, it is for PC use (in my experience). OP can you confirm?

Comment: @Eternallord66 Regarding the second part, check out our [Meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7523/if-an-answer-to-question-a-can-be-found-in-question-b-should-we-close-a-as-dupl) on duplication. I think this pretty clearly falls under the category of a question that is a precise subset of another question. "Where do I find X race" seems to me to be clearly a sub set of "Where can I find all of the races?". (of course assuming that we are only talking about the PC race)

Comment: yes I was talking about the pc race.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is found in Volo's Guide to Monsters.

Comment: And here it is on DnDB: https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/yuan-ti-pureblood

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure. I even have volvos guide on me now

Comment: Note: there are books from different editions this race is in.

Comment: This question was marked as 5e, not history of gaming, so mentioning other editions would be inappropriate.